# Check on page load if the page was Redirected using Response.Redirect or not

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I want to know whether or not the client got to the page he is now (for example "sign_up.aspx") using Response.Redirect or not. is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, as that would require a client response from a redirect, which isn't available in the methods to redirect either server/client side. Usually it's safe to assume they got there, unless the redirect URI is bad, in which *maybe* you can use some proxy magic to do something if they hit a specific HTTP response code. Edit: vacation was not good to my brain. Do what Matt said below

Answer (score 3):

You could just add a URL parameter in the redirect, then parse that on the client using JavaScript.

e.g `sign_up.aspx?source=from`

Comment: where should I put the piece of code? is it going to give me the string of the page redirected from?

Comment: That's not code, that's just pseudo code - without seeing more of your own code, I can't help you there.